# libtime_genoff.so error while building android

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build Cyanogenmod 12.1 with my ubuntu.
Target device is Korea G3(F400x).

I used TheMuppets's proprietary for vendor/lge/ and other things from Cyanogenmod github, and pulled needed files from Cyanogenmod 12 which is running on my phone.

But when I try to build...(using command "brunch f400k") I can see this.

```
make: *** `/home/newnis/android/system/out/target/product/f400k/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_servers_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_servers.so'에서 필요로 하는  타겟 `/home/newnis/android/system/out/target/product/f400k/obj/lib/libtime_genoff.so'를 만들 규칙이 없습니다.  멈춤.
```

This is korean message, I think this will mean:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/newnis/android/system/out/target/product/f400k/obj/lib/libtime_genoff.so` needed by `/home/newnis/android/system/out/target/product/f400k/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_servers_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_servers.so'. Stop.
```

in english.
I copied libandroid_servers.so from my phone, but result was same.
Also, I tried to find the libtime_genoff.so from my phone, but I could not find that.

I googled this problem, but I could not find any working solution.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it.

Something was wrong with device/lge/f400k.
It's name(f400k) wasn't matched with f400 in vendor/lge/g3-common/Android.mk

I changed directory name to f400(I edited some file's name and files in device/lge/f400, too.), and it works.

Now it looks like it's compiling well...